# How can we implement network search for Windows AND OS X clients?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, search

We have a network with Windows 7 and OS X (10.5 and 10.6) computers. Our servers run on Windows Server 2003 (1 Small Business Server, 2 Standard). We need to be able to search through about 15.000 - 30.000 documents in our archives.

The best solution would be if users can search directly from the Windows menu (on Windows 7) or the Spotlight menu (on OS X 10.5 and 10.6). Also good would be if users can search directly from the search bar in their browsers, or by first visiting a site with the search form. In case the users search through the browser, it's important they they are able to open a file in the search results just by clicking on it.

I have tested Microsoft Search Server Express, but it doesn't meet the requirements (no OS X support, results in the browser can't be opened by clicking in anything but Internet Explorer). I have looked at Spotlight server, but that only supports OS X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[Google Search Applicance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html)' maybe, they give you a machine for your intranet which does the indexing and the searching and you give them money.

Answer (score 1):

aside from google there are other search engines, '[xapian](http://xapian.org/)' (with the convinience package 'omega') or '[lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)' to name two. you could setup a box, let the indexers do their job and setup a little webpage for the intranet which searches in the index.

or you pay someone else money to do that for you, eg. '[flax](http://www.flax.co.uk/index.shtml)' has taken xapian as their base and then put some sugar onto it.

you can find similar projects surfing the '[powered by](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/PoweredBy)' page of lucene or the '[users](http://xapian.org/users)' page of xapian.

Comment: if that would earn me a new badge ... "fastest cleanup ever" :)

Answer (score -1):

another option would be '[google desktop search](http://desktop.google.com/)', but then every machine in the network would have to have access to all the files and would have to index all of the 30k documents by itself.